# where I can find the file sentimentTreesDebug.txt

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to analyze codes sentiment model anaysis of stanford corenlp, I have found on this page:

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/sentiment/SentimentTraining.java

but I can not find the "sentimentTreesDebug.txt" file with which to make the experiment, someone could tell me where that file or how it should look?

TrainPath String = "sentimentTreesDebug.txt";

I would appreciate very much the help or advice you could give me

this is my problem

xception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: MemoryTreebank.processFile IOException in file sentimentTreesDebug.txt
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.MemoryTreebank.processFile(MemoryTreebank.java:300)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.FilePathProcessor.processPath(FilePathProcessor.java:84)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.MemoryTreebank.loadPath(MemoryTreebank.java:152)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Treebank.loadPath(Treebank.java:193)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentUtils.readTreesWithLabels(SentimentUtils.java:67)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentUtils.readTreesWithGoldLabels(SentimentUtils.java:50)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentTraining.main(SentimentTraining.java:170)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: sentimentTreesDebug.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.MemoryTreebank.processFile(MemoryTreebank.java:212)
    ... 6 more
Java Result: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download them here:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/trainDevTestTrees_PTB.zip

A simple dev.txt would look like:

```
(4 (2 (2 Everything) (2 is)) (4 awesome))
```

HTH